# Not defined function from $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This one must be very simple. An external javascript file contains:

```
function Hello() {
    alert('Hello');
}
```

It is `getScript()`ed and then a contained function is called

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getScript('myscript.js');
    Hello();
</script>
```

I get:

> ReferenceError: Hello is not defined

But if the script is referenced in an HTML `<script>` tag it works as expected

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Hello();
</script>
```

What I am missing? How to reference objects created in a `getScript()`ed script? The reason I want to use `getScript()` it to load the script on a `ready()` event.

Comment: you didn't wait for the script to finish loading.

Comment: See the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). It's AJAX. Pay special attention to the second argument.

Comment: `$.getScript('myscript.js', function() { Hello(); });`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is that the `$.getScript()` function is asynchronous. When you call the `Hello()` function immediately after, the script is not yet loaded so the function is not available.

Loading scripts with regular `<script>` tags happens synchronously, so if you want to duplicate that behavior you have to disable the `async` option in your Ajax call.

`getScript` alone does not support this, so you can do this using an `$.ajax` call with the appropriate options:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'myscript.js',
     dataType: 'script',
     async: false
});
```

This will block the browser until the script is loaded.

However, a better technique is to use a callback, which `$.getScript()` does support:

```
$.getScript('myscript.js', function() {
    Hello();
});
```

Comment: both not working for me, any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014968/jquery-getscript-fails-to-load-function

Comment: missing comma after "    dataType: 'script'   "

Comment: jQuery should mention this importan msg in their blogs. Sucks...

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait for the response:

```
$.getScript('myscript.js', function(){
    Hello();
});
```